# Creating a document term matrix using fit_transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, cosine-similarity

I have an array that takes in string values from a json file. I want to create a document matrix to see the repeated words but when I pass in the array I get an error: 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

This is the line that gets the error all the time:
sparse_matrix = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(issues_description)

```
issues_description = []
    issues_key = []
    with open('issues_CLOVER.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for record in data:
            issues_key.append(record['key'])
            issues_description.append(record['fields']['description'])

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Key' : issues_key, 'Description' : issues_description})
    df.head(10)
```

This is the data that gets displayed:

```
       Key               Description
0   CLOV-1985   h2. Environment Details\r\n\r\nThis bug occurs...
1   CLOV-1984   Clover fails to instrument source code in case...
2   CLOV-1979   If a type argument for a parameterized type ha...
3   CLOV-1978   Bug affects Clover 3.3.0 and higher.\r\n\r\n \...
4   CLOV-1977   Add support to able to:\r\n * instrument sourc...
5   CLOV-1976   Add support to Groovy code in Clover for Eclip...
6   CLOV-1973   See also --CLOV-1956--.\r\n\r\nIn case HUDSON_...
7   CLOV-1970   Steps to reproduce:\r\n\r\nCoverage Explorer >...
8   CLOV-1967   Test Clover against IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 EAP (...
9   CLOV-1966   *Problem*\r\n\r\nClover Maven Plugin replaces ... 

    # Scikit Learn
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

    # Create the Document Term Matrix
    count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
    count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    sparse_matrix = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(issues_description)

    # OPTIONAL: Convert Sparse Matrix to Pandas Dataframe if you want to see the word frequencies.
    doc_term_matrix = sparse_matrix.todense()
    df = pd.DataFrame(doc_term_matrix, 
                      columns=count_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), 
                      index=[issues_key[0],issues_key[1],issues_key[2]])
    df
```

What do I change in order to get issues_description a passable arg or can someone point to me what I need to know in order for it to work?

Thanks.